# Equivalent Resistance in a short circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

[image]

Find the equivalent resistance across terminals a and c. I don't know how the current flows in this circuit so I can't find the equivalent resistance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What if you rearranged the elements like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feEq3F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then it's pretty simple to see the equivalent resistance is 6R/3 + R = 3R

Step one if you're stuck on a problem like this is to redraw it.