# What is the equivalent resistance?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, short-circuit

I have a circuit that I can't seem to understand how shrink down to one resistor. [image]

This is similar to another problem i found on this form ([Equivalent Resistance in a short circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83612/equivalent-resistance-in-a-short-circuit?answertab=oldest#tab-top)) however there wasn't much explanation as to how the answer was obtained. I was able to slightly redraw the circuit up to a certain point and couldn't procced.

[image]

If someone could please explain to me the process of solving these short circuit type of questions I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: (20 || 30 + 10) || 5. Just redraw the circuit and note that the 5 ohm resistor is between a and b.

Comment: @mario This does give me the correct answer but I really want to understand the logic on how you go the answer. To start off, how were you able to determine that the 20 and 30 were in parallel

Comment: @Fuzzy_Bunnys What do you mean by "you want to look at the connections at the nodes"

Comment: @James -- 20 and 30 are in parallel because both are connected to node a on one side and both are connected to the 10 ohm resistor on the other. Maybe you should redraw the circuit such, that the 20 and 30 ohm resistors are vertical, same as the 10 ohm resistor. The wire connecting the 20 and 30 ohm resistor is no longer needed and the solution should become obvious.

Comment: So a node is a point where two or more components meet. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_(circuits)

Comment: EDITED (wrong resistor values):you want to look at the connections at the nodes to figure out which are in parallel and which are in series. Here 20 and 30 are in parallel, and those are in series with 10, which are all in parallel with 5

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the definition of what a node is. where do  I go from there.

Answer (score 5):

Mario already answered your question, but you need a little visual aid. So, here's how you move components around. You should do this in your head, and with practice this will become natural.

[image]

As you can see, I am moving connections as if they were rubber bands. The important thing is not to cut them and to always make sure you preserve which component is attached to which node.

This is not the only way to transform that circuit: you could move R4 te other way around for example, but it pretty much shows how you can 'bend' your circuit without changing its property. 
Another way to do it, is to place your components unconnected in the way you like, and then drawing the connections between their terminals. For example, R4 here is connected between the leftmost node of R1 and the lower node of R3, so you could just place it there... It will come naturally after a while.

Comment: 1/2) First off I'd like to thank you for taking the time to draw this up for me, I really appreciate it. Now, this drawing makes a lot of sense to me and I understand what you did, however, wouldn't know how to really repeat this in another scenario. And if i were to try this, I feel like i would end up changing something that I wasn't allowed to change (making two items that were supposed to be connected in series, connect in parallel...etc). I wish there was a more formulaic of doing these changes.

Comment: 2/2) Another form (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79225/detecting-if-resistances-are-parallel-or-series-in-complex-circuits) helped me understand this a little bit more, however, I still am unsure if I would be able to replicate what you have done. I think this is only a problem when there is a short in the circuit because I have never had issues finding equivalent resistances before that. In some sense, I never paid attention to nodes and just went by the rules of combining items in series and items in parallel until one resistor remains.

Comment: @James: you are going to have to get good at recognizing equivalent topologies, no matter how they are drawn. You don't and cannot control the way others write their schematics. What I found works well for me is to take anyone's schematic and to completely redraw it from scratch, laying out the pieces I feel I do understand well in ways that I'm used to and understand well. This usually gets me pretty close to a cleaner layout for me and less personal confusion, in the end. But no matter what, you have to learn to rotate, flip, push, and pull bits and pieces. It's like algebraic manipulation.

Comment: @jonk I understand. What would be the best way of getting good at this?

Comment: Practice, practice and practice.

Comment: @James: Just get into practice redrawing schematics in different ways. I'll provide an answer here that does it for a circuit to see if that helps. (When I get time.) You already have some examples here. But more won't hurt and I'll take a different path, anyway. I'll also provide a consistent approach to solving nodes. But you need to be comfortable with math, too.

Comment: @jonk I would really appreciate that. I think for me the most important thing would be like you said, "a consistent approach to solving nodes". I really want to understand how to solve these types of problems but so far I don't see how I would continuously answer these problems.

Comment: @James - Jonk is correct, there **are** consistent approaches, but many of us don't have the patience (or algebra skills) to use them - we'd rather look for any short-cuts that simplify analysis. The short-cuts are a right-brain intuitive skill that is an art, defying explanation. So we are frustrated too, because communicating this skill is so difficult.

Comment: @glen_geek I completely understand. Since I am just learning this what would you say is the best way to achieve the end goal of being able to just look at the circuit and analyze it? Would it be to use the consistent approach until I can see the "pattern" that forms and at some point be able to just analyze the short circuit with no math?

Comment: @James - Yes, good plan. Concentrate on your left-brain where you can apply the rules of mesh, superposition, etc (consistent rules). Your right-brain skills will grow magically behind the scenes until one day, your right-brain will "see" a solution before your left-brain analysis grinds its way to the solution.

Comment: @glen_geek this is my plan but for short circuits schematics specifically would it just be practice and checking answers to see why it was done a certain way. In addition, if that's the case, where would I find more practice for short circuits schematics like I have shown in the picture (preferably with a redrawn circuit so I can try to figure out how the changes were done). I am willing to practice I just don't see how to.

Comment: @glen_geek In addition i tried trying following this guide to redrawing my circuit (http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-7/re-drawing-complex-schematics/) but wasn't getting the correct result. Any reason why there way may not have worked?

Comment: @james - I can only guess that you've mis-applied one of their rules. Perhaps you should keep searching for an analysis method that makes sense (makes sense to **you**). After grasping *one* method, the others come easier. Jonk has described a model of what makes V=IR "sing" for **him**, but it may not sing for **you**, or **me**.

Answer (score 3):

The same circuit, drawn differently.

Now it should be easy to see that R = (20 || 30 + 10) || 5.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpjFoi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: From this new drawing, I can clearly see R = (20 || 30 + 10) || 5. I have been going back and forth between this new drawing and the original drawing and can't see how you got from one to the other. I feel extremely stupid, however, I just can't see the connection.

Comment: Just take your drawing and rotate the 20 ohm resistor clockwise and the 30 ohm resistor counterclockwise. You could also number the nodes to check the equivalence.

Comment: So I understand how you manipulated the resistors, but not why you are allowed to manipulate them this way (ex. why can you just rotate the 20-ohm resistor clockwise). How would I get the equivalence by numbering the nodes?

Comment: Everything that is connected by a wire is called a node. In my drawing R1, R2 and R4 are connected to node a on one side. You can see that the same resistors are connected to node a in your schematic. You can do the same for node b and for the node in the middle which we could call node 1 or  node c. By checking the connections you can verify the equivalence.

Comment: @James think of connections as rubber bands: you can stretch and compress them as you like as long as you do not cut them or change what components are connected to any given node. If you respect this rule, you can move all components around as you see fit.

Comment: @Mario , just to make the question-answer more interesting: how would you solve the circuit if instead of that long short there was a resistor? I cannot find a way without wye-delta transformation. Can you find an easier way? EDIT: "long short", I love it!

Comment: @SredniVashtar What your saying only slightly makes sense to me. What about items in series and parallel, by moving things around that are "connected" could you not be changing that. I am still truly having a hard time understanding this and it's really frustrating me. Is there a video online that explains how these redraws are done.

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar - A delta-wye transformation would be a good solution. For a general solutionI would prefer to use a current source of 1A between a and b and solve the nodal equations. This way it could be programmed into a computer and solved without looking at the actual topology.

Comment: @SredniVashtar To be abundantly clear, it's the short that is the confusing part to me. If the short was removed, It is very clear to me how to reduce the circuit to a single resistor.

Comment: @James - You can shrink the short to a single dot by bringing the ends of the resistors together by moving them around. Start by making the short even shorter :-) until it is completely gone.

Comment: lol. Which way are you "moving them around" to make the short?

Comment: Take your 30 resistor and rotate counterclockwise by 180 degrees, move it up a little bit so that it does not end up on top of the 20 ohm resistor. The short should be gone. While you are at it move the 5 ohm resistor to the right between the terminals a and b.

Comment: @Mario I see what your saying I guess at the end of the day I just wouldn't think to do that because I wouldn't have even realized they were equivalent (If that makes any sense). I feel like there is something fundamental that I'm just not understanding.

Comment: @James -- These textbook circuits are often drawn in a way to confuse one with to purpose to train the analytical skills. So don't worry.

Comment: @james -- Count the # of nodes in the original circuit. It **looks** like there are four nodes, but two of them shrink together (thru the "short")...there are only three nodes. Shrinking nodes often makes circuit analysis much easier, it is a skill worth developing.

Comment: @glen_geek I understand that there are only really 3 nodes, however how do you shrink them together in you mind.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your circuit in three different ways. All of them equivalent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTMOx2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The one on the upper left is your original circuit, but with labeled resistors and an added node called ***c***. That's the one you are trying to solve. Now take a look to the right of it, at the top right. It's the exact same circuit. You can test this out. Look what node (a) touches -- \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, and \$R_4\$. That's the same set of resistors that (a) touches on the upper left schematic, too! Now go around and check out each of the three nodes to see what they touch and don't touch and what ends of which, too. If you go around and compare the two upper ones, you'll find they are the same.

Now look at the bottom one. Looks really different, doesn't it? But it is the same as the other two. But here, I think, you may be able to more easily see how to analyze it. Now you can easily see that \$R_1\$ and \$R_4\$ are in parallel with each other; and that this parallel equivalent is in series with \$R_3\$; and that all of that is in parallel with \$R_2\$. It almost just falls out.

The result should be:

$$\begin{align*}
R &= \left(\;\;\left[R_1 \vert\vert R_4\right] + R_3\;\;\right)\;\; \vert\vert \;\; R_2 \\
R &= \left(\;\;\left[20\Omega \vert\vert 30\Omega\right] + 10\Omega\;\;\right)\;\; \vert\vert \;\; 5\Omega \\
R &= \left(\;\;12\Omega + 10\Omega\;\;\right)\;\; \vert\vert \;\; 5\Omega \\
R &= 22\Omega\;\; \vert\vert \;\; 5\Omega \\
R &\approx 4.074\Omega
\end{align*}$$

I now want you to look at the bottom schematic again. If we happened to know the voltage at ***a*** and happened to also know the voltage at ***b***, and could solve for the voltage at ***c***, then we could work out all the currents and from that we could figure out the total resistance.

So let's do something entirely different.

I want you to look at node ***c*** there. Think of some specific (but currently unknown) voltage as just laying there somehow. Let's call it \$V_c\$. Let your mind just imagine that \$V_c\$ is instead like a concrete landing along a stairway between the bottom floor below (at ***b***) and the next floor up (at ***a***.) On this concrete landing, a *voltage* pours out and flows on that landing and reaches the edges and flows away to somewhere. You can't quite see where, though. But you can see the flow as it leaves the edge of the landing and disappears away off into the distance. This flow is *current*.

Now, also imagine that at the same time there are other flows elsewhere. Some of those flows wind up flowing onto your landing here at \$V_c\$. And so you have some outward flows of current leaving your landing and you have some incoming flows from other landings or floors (in this case, just ***a*** and ***b***.)

Now, for the level of your landing to stay the same, these flows must equal each other -- otherwise, you have a time dependent level and we are assuming that this isn't happening.

(In real life, current cannot accumulate or bleed out of a node, because electric charges are SO VERY POWERFUL that you could literally move the entire planet Earth if you could just accumulate a small mass of charges. Mass is almost always nearly perfectly neutral.)

Okay. So here is how we say this in math-lingo. Let's write down the flows away from our landing:

$$ \frac{V_c}{R_1}+\frac{V_c}{R_4}+\frac{V_c}{R_3} $$

Do you see that? Your landing voltage flows away from your landing *through* those resistors to *somewhere*. It's not important where, right now. It's just important that you realize that this represents the sum of the outward going flows for this landing. Those are the only exits from it. So that is all there is.

Now, let's look at what is coming back in. To do that, we now get to peak at the ***other side*** of each resistor (those we just looked at for the outward flows) to see what is flowing back inward towards our landing:

$$ \frac{V_a}{R_1}+\frac{V_a}{R_4}+\frac{V_b}{R_3} $$

Now, as I said, these two have to be equal to each other. So the following must be a true equation:

$$ \frac{V_c}{R_1}+\frac{V_c}{R_4}+\frac{V_c}{R_3}=\frac{V_a}{R_1}+\frac{V_a}{R_4}+\frac{V_b}{R_3} $$

Let's do some algebraic manipulation now:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_c}{R_1}+\frac{V_c}{R_4}+\frac{V_c}{R_3}&=\frac{V_a}{R_1}+\frac{V_a}{R_4}+\frac{V_b}{R_3} \\
V_c\cdot\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_4}+\frac{1}{R_3}\right)&=\frac{V_a}{R_1}+\frac{V_a}{R_4}+\frac{V_b}{R_3} \\
V_c&=\left(\frac{V_a}{R_1}+\frac{V_a}{R_4}+\frac{V_b}{R_3}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_4}+\frac{1}{R_3}} \\
V_c&=\left(\frac{V_a}{R_1}+\frac{V_a}{R_4}+\frac{V_b}{R_3}\right)\cdot\frac{R_1\cdot R_3\cdot R_4}{R_1\cdot R_3 +R_1\cdot R_4 +R_3\cdot R_4} \\
V_c&=\frac{V_a\cdot R_3\cdot R_4 +V_a\cdot R_1\cdot R_3+V_b\cdot R_1\cdot R_4}{R_1\cdot R_3\cdot R_4}\cdot\frac{R_1\cdot R_3\cdot R_4}{R_1\cdot R_3 +R_1\cdot R_4 +R_3\cdot R_4} \\
V_c&=\frac{V_a\cdot R_3\cdot R_4 +V_a\cdot R_1\cdot R_3+V_b\cdot R_1\cdot R_4}{R_1\cdot R_3 +R_1\cdot R_4 +R_3\cdot R_4}
\end{align*}$$

Now for another little tidbit. In any schematic we look at, we can assign any node the value of exact 0 -- \$0V\$. We get to do that exactly once per circuit. (Actually, you could assign any value once. But \$0V\$ makes things slightly easier. So that's what we do. In this case, we are going to say \$V_a=0V\$. Now, we are also going to set \$V_b=10\$ for convenience, and see what happens regarding currents. If we can figure out the current and we already know the voltage then we can figure out the resistance, too.

$$\begin{align*}
V_c&=\frac{0V\cdot 10\Omega\cdot 30\Omega +0V\cdot 20\Omega\cdot 10\Omega+10V\cdot 20\Omega\cdot 30\Omega}{20\Omega\cdot 10\Omega +20\Omega\cdot 30\Omega +10\Omega\cdot 30\Omega} \\
V_c&= 5\tfrac{45}{99}V
\end{align*}$$

Now we can compute the total currents! Look at node ***b***. There are only two ways for current to flow from there and then on towards ***a***. Right? So if we total up the currents for \$R_3\$ and \$R_2\$ then we will have all of the currents added up!

$$\begin{align*}
I_{R_3} &= \frac{V_b-V_c}{R_3} = \frac{10V-5\tfrac{45}{99}V}{10\Omega} = \tfrac{45}{99}A \\
I_{R_2} &= \frac{V_b-V_a}{R_2} = \frac{10V - 0V}{5\Omega} = 2A \\
I_{total} &= I_{R_2} + I_{R_3} = 2A + \tfrac{45}{99}A = 2\tfrac{45}{99}A \\
R &= \frac{V_b-V_a}{I_{total}} = \frac{10V-0V}{2\tfrac{45}{99}A} =\frac{10V}{2\tfrac{45}{99}A} \approx 4.074\Omega
\end{align*}$$

Same answer!

It's really important that you learn to *think* in different ways here. It greatly simplifies the world around you if you can pick up a few truly powerful ideas that help you simplify an otherwise very complicated looking world.

I hope that helps some.

But you really do need to practice redrawing schematics on your own. There is no getting around that work ahead.

Comment: Wow, thank you for writing all this up, as with everyone else on this thread (but yours particularly) thank you for taking the time to write this up. It was truly an interesting approach to the problem and I enjoyed the "thinking outside the box" aspect of it, i think it definitely gave me a better understanding. In terms of moving forward with determining short circuit schematics, would you just say keep practising them until it makes sense is the best approach? Thanks again.

Comment: @jonk - Well done. James, I'd suggest that Jonk's approach is "thinking *inside* the box". Textbooks describe similar methods of circuit analysis quite well. I would grab a few, and start reading about superposition, mesh and node analysis. It often happens that the *last* book in the pile is written by a **brilliant** author that makes perfect sense. Its always the last book! (Takes me 5-6 books before it sinks in ;-)

Comment: @glen_geek: Find a textbook that describes nodal analysis the way I just did? Let me know. Most use something a little more arcane as a mental process (though of course equivalent.) The idea of "spilling" arrived as an equivalent concept and, for me, was easier to keep in mind. It "sang" to me. Something similar happened to me with calculus. The mid-late 1800's Dedekind/Weierstrass limit theorem is truly a Rube Goldberg contraption compared to accepting the idea of infinitesimal variable algebra -- luckily, Abraham Robinson revived it in his non-standard analysis in the mid 1960's.

Answer (score 0):

James question specifically involves dealing with short-circuits. I'd like to point out that this is an *essential* step in applying Thevenin's Theorem. Similarly, modifying a circuit to break a path is an *essential* step in applying Norton's Theorem. These two Theorems are very important circuit analysis tools that must be mastered by every electrical engineer.
Adding a short circuit to an existing circuit in applying Thevenin's Theorem is the easy part. Identifying the circuit's parts that are modified (or eliminated) is an **art** that requires re-imagining, re-arranging or re-drawing the circuit to its new form. I would suggest to James that mastering Thevenin's Theorem is the key to attaining the art of "seeing" how short-circuits modify a network.
Here's an exercise that James might try....
**Take *any* circuit (start with a simple one). Draw it upside down. Verify that it is the *same* circuit in the electrical sense.** This will start to develop the art of mentally re-arranging circuit elements.
Once you've gained confidence doing this, tackle a problem involving Thevenin's Theorem. A huge variety of books and websites present solution scenarios.
http://www.electricaltechnology.org/2014/01/thevenins-theorem.html 
As with any **art**, solving that *first* is often hugely difficult and frustrating.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is important I realize that I know what causing me the trouble and it's the short circuits. I am assuming that you are talking about the step in Thevenin's theorem where you short voltage sources and open current sources (step 3 in your example).

Comment: @James - Yes, exactly. Some short-cuts were made in that step-3 example. A short-circuit was initially applied *in parallel* with the battery. Then it was realized (this is part of the art that you're trying to develop) that the short dominates and eliminates the battery. After that, it was realized that the 12K and the 4K resistor are in parallel - (this is *also* part of the art that you're trying to develop).